# 500 Error with lightbox form after using checkValidity for Email Validation

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I recently asked a question about getting email validation to work on a form with and unsubscribe button that sprouts a confirmation form. Someone helped me by telling me to use Javascript's `.checkValidity()` API, which worked for checking the validation, but caused another problem: now, when the user enters a valid email and clicks "Unsubscribe", it fails to load the lightbox form and results in a 500 error.

The closest I've got it to working is removing the `<form/>` encapsulation, which doesn't allow the user to submit the email if it's invalid, but it doesn't provide any notification to the user that/why it's invalid. If the user enters a valid email, everything works as desired.

Here's the code in question, along with the fiddle:

```html
   <script src="//app-ab21.marketo.com/js/forms2/js/forms2.min.js"></script>
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
    MktoForms2.loadForm('//app-ab21.marketo.com',  '726-BWN-173', 1008);
    MktoForms2.whenReady(function(form) {
      document.querySelector('#lightboxButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if(Email.checkValidity()) {
          form.addHiddenFields({
            Email: Email.value
          });
          MktoForms2.lightbox(form).show();
        }
      });
    });
  });
document.getElementById("mktoForm_1008").onsubmit= function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
}
</script>
<form id="mktoForm_1008"></form>
<form>
<input id="Email" type="email" placeholder="Email address" required size = "55px">
<button id="lightboxButton" type="submit" onclick="submitform()">Unsubscribe</button>
</form>
```

Fiddle w/ CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/r6psz2bq/1/

Thanks!